# ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex returns null

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

I have a dataBinding ListBox in a Pivot section.

In another Pivot section i have a form to create new items for the ListBox.

When i add a new item to the ListBox i need to acces to the new ListBoxItem for find a TextBox control and modify the Text value, but

```
ListBoxItem lbItem = allItemsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(itemIndex) as ListBoxItem;
```

Always returns null.

The problem seems to be that the ListBox is not visible, so the new ListBoxItem is virtual.

How can i resolve that?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot get ItemContainers until they are generated. The ListBox has to be rendered for that first.

Comment: And there is another way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use data binding with DataTemplates instead of trying to modify the controls directly?

for example:

Code:

```
// Data binding class
public class Data
{
    // Implement INofifyPropertyChanged
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

// Code to bind it to Pivot

ObservableCollection<Data> list = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
// populate list
Pivot1.ItemsSource = list;
```

XAML:

```
<Pivot Name="Pivot1">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Now, to change Text of a specific TextBlock, all you need to do is change a value of associated Data object to it from the list.

Comment: I'm already using data binding on the ListBox but my template has two controls, a TextBlock and a TextBox, and the source for both is different.

So, the only way is to make a new class wich combines both collections and then databind the ListBox with it or there is another way?

Thanks.